# How to draw alternative route in graphhopper?

Tags: graphhopper

I have working on routing application . I need to draw alternative route . Please suggest me how to possible it to change code or some thing else

Comment: are you using the dev branch https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/pull/420 or what is your setup?

Comment: @karussell yes I am also using  same setup

Comment: As the branch is not yet finished. You'll need to refactor the code because the alternative routes are returned as one Path.

Comment: Hm, I thought that GH has special branch `alternative_route` for that. What is its status, is it finished?

Answer (score 0):

i have done code to show alternative roots Thanks karussell For Your Suggestion